# How to actually use JAWR with a library from a CDN

Tags: cdn, jawr

We use JAWR to serve content, but would like to also make use of a CDN to distribute scripts. For instance, to use jQuery, we have:

```
jawr.js.bundle.jquery.id=/bundles/jquery.js
jawr.js.bundle.jquery.mappings=/js/lib/.license,/js/lib/jquery-1.8.2.js
jawr.js.bundle.jquery.productionURL=http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js
```

That works great. We get the local library in debug mode, and the one from CDN in production mode. However, let’s add:

```
jawr.js.bundle.bootstrap.id=/bundles/bootstrap.js
jawr.js.bundle.bootstrap.mappings=/js/lib/bootstrap-2.1.0/js/.license,/js/lib/bootstrap-2.1.0/js/bootstrap.js
jawr.js.bundle.bootstrap.dependencies=jquery
```

Now, upon access (not upon startup) of a page using `/bundles/bootstrap.js`, JAWR throws a nasty exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The bundleDataHashCode must be set before accessing the url prefix.
    at net.jawr.web.resource.bundle.JoinableResourceBundleImpl.getURLPrefix(JoinableResourceBundleImpl.java:560)
    ...
    at net.jawr.web.taglib.AbstractResourceBundleTag.doStartTag(AbstractResourceBundleTag.java:68)
    ...
```

Does that mean I cannot depend on a bundle with a `productionURL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open issue on JAWR about this and a thread (without any answers) in the forum. The answer (from myself) for now is:

> You can use `productionURL`, but do not depend on these bundles. All that is broken
>   is the dependency mechanism. Manually adding all the necessary `<jawr:.../>` tags works.

Comment: Versino 3.5.1 of JAWR promises to fix just that.